# Google scraping using python - requests: How to avoid being blocked due to many requests?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, python-requests

For a school project I need get the web addresses of 200 companies (based on a list). My script is working fine, but when I'm around the company 80, I get blocked by google. This is the message that I'm getting.

```
> Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network. 
> This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and
> not a robot.  <a href="#"
> onclick="document.getElementById('infoDiv').style.display='block'
```

I tried two different ways to get my data:

A simple one:

```
for company_name in data:
     search = company_name
     results = 1
     page = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q={}&num={}".format(search, results))

     soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")
```

and a more complex on:

```
for company_name in data:
    search = company_name
    results = 1

    s = requests.Session()
    retries = Retry(total=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
    s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
    s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
    page = s.get("https://www.google.com/search?q={}&num={}".format(search, results))
    #time.sleep(.600)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")
```

But I'm getting the same mistake over and over. Is there a way I could overcome this issue? thanks!

Comment: Start by inserting a delay between the requests. Proceed by specifying the User-Agent field.

Comment: Have you checked Google's terms of service? If you're violating them by using using an automated scraper on their site, there really is no way to "fix" that—whatever you do is breaking the rules, and if they can detect that you're doing it (and they're Google, they can detect a lot…) they'll break your code. If you're only violating them by making too many requests, there's probably something that tells you how many is "too many", so you can insert delays to stay below that limit.

Comment: @DYZ, where in the script and how can I include that?

Comment: @abarnert, I'm just doing too many requests. I'm trying to find the limit. I would like to know how can I make the requests on batches.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to make sure you never make more than 1 request every 0.6 seconds, you just need to sleep until it's been at least 0.6 seconds since the last request.

If the amount of time it takes you to process each request is a tiny fraction of 0.6 seconds, you can uncomment the line already in your code. However, it probably makes more sense to do it at the end of the loop, rather than in the middle:

```
for company_name in data:
    # blah blah
    page = s.get("https://www.google.com/search?q={}&num={}".format(search, results))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")
    # do whatever you wanted with soup
    time.sleep(.600)
```

---

If your processing takes a sizable fraction of 0.6 seconds, then waiting 0.6 seconds is too long. For example, if it sometimes takes 0.1 seconds, sometimes 1.0, then you want to wait 0.5 seconds in the first case, but not at all in the second, right?

In that case, just keep track of the last time you made a request, and sleep until 0.6 seconds after that:

```
last_req = time.time()
for company_name in data:
    # blah blah
    page = s.get("https://www.google.com/search?q={}&num={}".format(search, results))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")
    # do whatever you wanted with soup

    now = time.time()
    delay = last_req + 0.600 - now
    last_req = now
    if delay >= 0:
        time.sleep(delay)
```

---

If you need to make requests *exactly* once every 0.6 seconds—or as close to that as possible—you could kick off a thread that does that, and tosses the results in a queue, while another thread (possibly your main thread) just blocks popping requests off that queue and processing them.

But I can't imagine why you'd need that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adjusting your user-agent headers to something other than the `python requests` default.  In doing so I was able to search for all **949** companies from https://www.sec.gov/rules/other/4-460list.htm with no issues.

My default user-agent is:

```
print requests.utils.default_headers()

{'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.8.1'}
```

Which **Google** might detect as **unusual traffic**

```
user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/602.2.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.1 Safari/602.2.14'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent,'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'}

for company_name in data:
    search = company_name
    results = 1
    page = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q={}&num={}".format(search, results), headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")
    print company_name
    print soup.find('h3', attrs={'class':'r'}).text
    print soup.find('h3', attrs={'class':'r'}).find('a').attrs['href']
```