# Why urlopen gives response 200 while request give 403?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

to reproduce the situation

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
site= 'https://www.ssense.com/en-hk/women/dresses'
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
print(page.getcode())
```

the above return response 200, while request return 403 below

```
import requests
page = requests.get('https://www.ssense.com/en-hk/women/dresses',headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
print(page.status_code)
```

Note: A funny issue is after request return 403, urlopen return 403 when executed immediately. Waiting for a few minutes, urlopen gives 200 again

I would like to ask

1. is it safe to use urlopen in this case? as most people recommend request over urlopen
2. if possible, please answer why this happen? as people mentioned they are similar

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try to change the other headers too. // possible duplicate of [Google scrapping using python - requests: How to avoid being blocked due to many requests? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953855/google-scrapping-using-python-requests-how-to-avoid-being-blocked-due-to-many)

Comment: It's probably a coincidence. If you try a few more times the former may fail or the latter may succeed as well. You are probably being rate limited. They both work for me.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I tried adding Retry according to the post by @user202729 . It still did not work for me and I tried using header like 
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 on x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.63 Safari/537.36'}

Comment: @Selcuk thank you for giving a try. I wonder why mine did not work. I tired on different dates as well. Is it possible for me to modify the request code to make it work?

Comment: No one can now but the admins of the site in question. They might have blacklisted your IP address, might be rate limiting you, or something else.

Comment: Yeah, it's Cloudflare security to avoid DDoS. You may use proxies with selenium to avoid rate limiting. For best results I use multiple proxies and headers with selenium, combine them and you'll get a new identity to avoid rate-limiting

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I would try using multiple proxies and headers. Both urllib and request may occasionally return 403. Using selenium with one header will lead to 'please identify you are human, please use javascript and cookies in your browser' check when reaching ~400 calls. Let me try again

Answer (score -1):

Try with these headers:

```
accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
cache-control:max-age=0
cookie:__cfduid=d56f8520d4458142c4dbd8eb36def3efe1609917283; _pxhd=416cf49200eb4c7587efba54abbaf59d0af556f200f05294430e0eea3876d8e2:d9d2e561-4fee-11eb-800c-4dfb4f618dd4; gdprCountry=true; cookieDisclaimerAccepted=false; visitorId=306deb7876a82deeb476f8a298596783b5be9297840f1af7e62890c32cb1e22d; forcedCountry=HK; preferredLanguage=en; is_markdown_ab_enabled=false; is_new_login_redirect_enabled=false; isp=tellcom iletisim hizmetleri a.s.; sid=5d2dd6802ab257fb54241b9abd68f965; lang=en_US; country=HK; _pxvid=d9d2e561-4fee-11eb-800c-4dfb4f618dd4; SSP_AB_fitpredictor=unallocated; _sp_ses.c6c8=*; shopping_bag=5ff56365a586bf5209e70946; _ga=GA1.2.1168695953.1609917285; _gid=GA1.2.1924545488.1609917285; rskxRunCookie=0; rCookie=15j0zp1rukg7162cv0n3bkjl36o18; __zlcmid=121jiLgFhxWISE7; _dd_s=rum=0&expire=1609918213509; _sp_id.c6c8=89852b8a-60e9-4408-904e-67e68c40c34e.1609917284.1.1609917314.1609917284.06c44494-676b-4024-91ca-03cb15d3fa22; lastRskxRun=1609917314864; _px2=eyJ1IjoiZWJiODBhZDAtNGZlZS0xMWViLTlmZGUtYWYzMTAyMzk3NDVlIiwidiI6ImQ5ZDJlNTYxLTRmZWUtMTFlYi04MDBjLTRkZmI0ZjYxOGRkNCIsInQiOjE2MDk5MTc2MTY1NzksImgiOiI5NDBhNDc5YzQzMWIxOTEwOGQ4ZDVkMDIyMDNhZjFlZjEyYzc5ZDg1MDI0ZmI3OWE5NWM3YjEyZjcyYjI1MjJiIn0=
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"
sec-ch-ua-mobile:?0
sec-fetch-dest:document
sec-fetch-mode:navigate
sec-fetch-site:none
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests:1
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
```